# Listing of awarded bounties

Tags: support, bounty, statistics

Is there any way of seeing the bounties that have been awarded over the last quarter or month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com) query. [Here's one that I just wrote](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/revision/272695/356035/):

```
SELECT PostId as [Post Link], BountyAmount, CreationDate
FROM Votes
-- VoteTypeId 8 = bounty posted on question, 9 = bounty awarded on answer
WHERE VoteTypeId = 9
AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, CreationDate, GETDATE()) < 1
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

It shows all bounties awarded this month. To customize it, in the second to last line, replace `MONTH` with any arbitrary time period (DAY, WEEK, etc.) and `1` with how many of those time periods ago you want to view (i.e. replace it with `4` to see all bounties awarded on answers in the past 4 months).